# ICE connectivity check

Tags: webrtc, stun, sdp, turn

In a typical case, I have two endpoints A & B, and have a turn server say S. A initiated call and send host and relay candidate to B in SDP. B answered call and sent only host candidate in SDP.

Lets say A's candidates are
host: 192.168.1.150:5555
relay: 192.168.1.100:7890

B's host candidate is
host: 192.168.1.151:5690

Say turn server details are as below
192.168.1.100:3478

Now I am about to start ICE connectivity check from A towards B.

First I tried connectivity check from A's host candidate to B's host candidate. It timed out, and its ok.

Next I am about to try ICE connectivity from A's relayed candidate to B's host candidate. Here my doubt is, when A send connectivity check (which is STUN BIND request), to which transport it will send.

Possible cases are, 
1) A will send from host transport address to turn server 192.168.1.100:3478

2) A will send from host transport address to A's relay candidate 192.168.1.100:7890

Which one above is correct as per ICE standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A will send from a random local udp port previous used when allocating the relay candidate on the TURN server to 192.168.1.100:3478. This will usually be a send indication containing the ICE binding request and specifying Bs host candidate as destination. The turn server will send this from port 7890 to the host candidate of B

Comment: Thanks Philipp. In this case connectivity request (stun bind)  will go directly or over channel?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's likely that ICE will not succeed. A will send from host transport address to turn server 192.168.1.100:3478 and then server will try to forward the packet through port 7890 as raw data (not TURN encapsulated) but as the peer has NATted host so that will not reach to B. Also B will try to send packets to A's relay candidate but server will not allow this packet as A set permission for B's 192.168.1.151 but server will not see this address but the public address of B which has no permission to go through.